Is Runge-Kutte integration possible with an infinite boundary condition?
I have a 2nd order differential equation of the form: $$\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \rho^2} + \frac{3}{\rho} \frac{d \Phi}{d \rho} = \Phi - \frac{3}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Phi^3$$ with boundary conditions $\Phi(\infty) = \Phi_{fv}$ and $\frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}|_{\rho=0} = 0$. $\alpha$ here is simply a free variable. As far as I am aware this equation has no analytic solution so I have been trying numerical techniques; in particular Runge-Kutta integration. By defining $ u = \frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}$, this can be reduced to the system of equations : $$u = \frac{d \Phi}{d\rho}$$ and $$u'  = -  \frac{3}{\rho}u +\Phi - \frac{3}{2} \Phi^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Phi^3 $$ but I find I hit a wall here. The main problems I have are that:
A) My boundary condition for $\Phi$ only holds in a limit and RK integration is iterative so I would need a specific value of $\Phi(\rho)$ to iterate upon
and
B) The "reduced" first order differential equation still contains 3 "orders" of derivatives.
Where can I go from here? Is there a more sensible approach to this ODE?

Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894015/how-to-solve-numerically-2nd-order-ode-with-boundary-conditions-at-both-ends?rq=1 ?
If you take some value, say $\rho_0 = 10$ and $\Phi(0) = s$ ($s$ being your parameter). You can propagate the solution from left (starting with $\rho = 0$) up to $\rho_o$ and also from a very large $\rho$ you propagate backwards to same $\rho_0$. You search for the $s$ value where you have a match between the left and the right values.

Something like this but update with your parameters
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = 0.25
Phi_fv = -2.0  
rho0 = 1e-5
rho_max = 50

rho = np.linspace(rho0, rho_max, 500)

def sys(rho, y):
    Phi, u = y
    dPhi_drho = u
    du_drho = - (3 / rho) * u + Phi - (3/2) * Phi**2 + (alpha / 2) * Phi**3
    return np.vstack((dPhi_drho, du_drho))

def bc(ya, yb):
    Phi_a, u_a = ya
    Phi_b, u_b = yb
    return np.array([u_a, Phi_b - Phi_fv])

y_init = np.zeros((2, rho.size))
y_init[0, :] = 1

res = solve_bvp(sys, bc, rho, y_init)

print(res.message)

plt.plot(res.x, res.y[0], label='Phi(rho)')
plt.xlabel('rho')
plt.ylabel('Phi')
plt.show()

